# Using the swap space of Windows 3.1 as a MS-DOS 6.22 temporary directory

Tags: ms-dos, windows-3.x

I currently have a working installation of MS-DOS 6.22 with Windows 3.1. I can only use Windows or DOS individually so I don't see the point of having a swap-file for Windows taking up space that can't be used for the DOS `%TEMP%` directory.

Let's assume that I have a separate `%TEMP%` directory for when Windows starts. How can I configure DOS to overwrite the Windows swap area with the contents of the `%TEMP%` directory?

Comment: I don't really think it is useful to have a swap file for DOS in a relatively modern computer that has enough memory to properly use HIMEM.SYS and EMM386

Comment: @tofro In a _modern_ computer, no. But in an original machine, yes.

Comment: You could delete the Windows swap file when running MS-DOS and when running Windows recreate the swap file and delete the contents of the TEMP directory. I don't think this going to worth the effort though. You'd need to have MS-DOS applications that need the extra disk space, and Windows applications that need the extra virtual memory but not the extra disk space. And be willing to put up with the longer startup times this would require.

Comment: @RossRidge That's exactly what the setup is for. Does the swap file have to have a particular format? (Also, wouldn't deleting the swap file allow the space required to become fragmented and not be big enough for a continuous swap file?)

Comment: Fragmentation could be a problem, yes, but I don't see any way else to make the disk space taken up by the Windows swap file generally available to MS-DOS applications. One thing that makes my suggestion easier to implement is that Windows 3.1 supports using a temporary swap file that it will automatically delete on exit and recreate on startup.

Comment: @RossRidge TSR? That might be able to hook into the disk I/O and trick DOS into thinking that there's no file there. This TSR could then be overwritten by Windows or unhooked just before `win` is run.

Comment: If you're willing to write code to implement something then a lot things are possible. Just run your MS-DOS applications under Windows and the Windows swap file will be used to provide virtual memory to those applications as necessary. However I don't know of any existing solution that will do something like this that isn't Windows or an entire operating system itself. Maybe DESQView?

Comment: @RossRidge I'll have a look.

Comment: Is DESQView open-sourced, @RossRidge? I remember hearing that QuarterDeck (now Symantec) released it into the public domain some years back, but I can't remember if the source code was ever published. And now, of course, 10+ years later, I can't find any extant references to it online.

Comment: @CodyGray I have no clue about the current status of DESQView. I'm only vaguely familiar the product itself, mostly from references in Ralf Brown's Interrupt List.

Comment: @Cody DESQview was never open-sourced, just released as freeware. It used to be available from [chsoft.com](http://www.chsoft.com/dv.html), but the FTP server has disappeared. [oldskool.org](ftp://ftp.oldskool.org/pub/misc/Software/DESQ/) still has it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting and recreating the swap file is a really bad idea for reasons in comments.

Here follows an insane idea that would work if you pulled it off.

1) Create Permanent Swap File; ensure its contiguous. This is best done with a disk editor to ensure you also align on a cylinder boundary. Thankfully defrag.exe is sane enough to not move the windows swap file.

2) Create overlapping primary partition so that it aligns with the the swap file. I will now assume that this ends up on `D:`; replace script references as necessary

3) Add lines to autoexec.bat:

```
FORMAT D: /Q < Y.CHR > NUL
MD D:\TEMP
SET TMP=D:\TEMP
SET TEMP=D:\TEMP
```

3) Make C:\WINDOWS\TEMP if it doesn't already exist

4) Rename win.com to runwin.com

5) Create win.bat as follows

```
subst D: C:\WINDOWS
runwin.com
subst D: /D
FORMAT D: /Q < C:\Y.CHR > NUL
MD D:\TEMP
```

6) Create Y.CHR

```
echo Y> C:\Y.CHR
```

7) Reboot

The subst command can be used to mask off drives you don't want to be able to access. I've done this in the past when I had two paths to the same disk so I got two drive letters for it, and drove `smartdrv.exe` bonkers.

Does it work? Yes. Are you going to regret it if you ever reconfigure your windows swap file again? Yes.

Comment: When I read the question my first thought was to write a loadable device driver that would let you mount the swap file as an extra drive, but this is probably neater, as long as you're happy using full cylinders for the job...

Comment: @Jules: That's what I thought too, but who has the expertise for that these days? A quick attempt at finding one didn't.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you shouldn't do that. It will be sloooow, and won't be worth the time spent on it, mostly because old hard drives are kinda slow and not very useful in terms of using them as swap. Besides that, it may lead to slowing down the HDD or even HDD malfunction, where you may not be able to restore the data (old HDDs are mostly heavily-used ones, and making a new swapfile will make things even worse in terms of write-count).

The easiest solution would be adding something like that to the begining of `AUTOEXEC.BAT`:

```
DEL swapfile.sys
MKDIR C:/DOS/TMP
SET TEMP=C:/DOS/TMP
```

Where swapfile.sys is the name of your swapfile.

Then, the best approach is probably creating a script that will look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Creating swapfile.sys, please wait...
FOR /l %i in (1,1,1000) DO ECHO. > swapfile.sys
WIN.COM
```

Comment: *"mostly because old hard drives are kinda slow and not very useful in terms of using them as swap."* Yes, but old *computers* are also kinda slow. The *relative* difference between computational power and disk-access speed was *much* smaller in the DOS days than it is now. Also, swap space isn't used for performance reasons. It's used to allow you to do things that you couldn't otherwise use because you don't have enough physical RAM.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, sometimes having SWAP on a slow hard drive makes performance worse(even taking other old hardware into consideration), that's what i was trying to write.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating a Windows swap in a batch file like this. Windows 3.1 can create its own temporary swap file as necessarily, while a file with a 1000 blank lines is unlikely to work as a permanent swap file. Also `FOR /l` won't work in MS-DOS. That, and any of the other FOR options, requires that the script be run using `cmd.exe` under a Windows NT based OS. You also need to use backslashes (\\) instead of forward slashes (/) in your path names.

Comment: It is true that the swap file should generally be placed on the fastest disk you have available. However, it is not true that simply having a swap file makes performance slower. In a sane implementation of virtual memory, the swap file wouldn't even be used unless it was necessary because physical memory was full. (That's sort of beginning to change on modern systems, with caching and memory compression, but these ideas are very new, weren't ever used on retro systems, and wouldn't make sense there anyway for a variety of reasons.) What you were saying just isn't true.

Comment: Another reason not to do this: the Windows 386 swap file *must be contiguously allocated on the disk*, which this approach doesn't guarantee.

Comment: Having a swap file will definitely make things slower. Obviously, if your memory is under pressure, the swapping will significantly degrade memory access times. Also, the content of the paging file needs to be tracked which takes up significant memory. Also, with win16 I don't think virtual memory is used unless you have a swap file as all applications share the same address space. The address calculation requires extra memory accesses into the page table, which will slow things down.

Comment: @JeremyP - the Windows 3 swap file is never used unless it is necessary.  The amount of memory required to track usage is minimal, so shouldn't cause degradation in anything other than exceptional cases.  Win16 *does* use virtual memory (in standard and 386 enhanced modes) whether or not you have a swap file -- sections of program/dll files can be deleted from memory and reloaded from the program later. Using a swap file might prevent this from happening, which will speed the system up, because this process is often much slower than swapping due to disk fragmentation issues.

Comment: Therefore I don't believe having a swap file in windows 3 will ever degrade performance in real world cases: in any case where the swap file is used, you'd be seeing program segments and resources being removed from memory instead and that is likely to slow the system down still further.  And once that possibility is exhausted, the system would crash.  On the whole, I think having a swap file is better than not having one. (Also note that the swap file is not paging: entire segments are moved into and out of it at once. There are no page tables in win16, even when the swap file is being used.)